# How to use Powershell to find pdfs in directories that are image based (Windows Environment)?

Tags: powershell, pdf, itext

I am an absolute newbie as far as Powershell goes. I found a script here - https://www.litigationsupporttipofthenight.com/single-post/2020/04/19/powershell-script-to-count-words-lines-and-characters-in-multiple-pdfs - that I thought was exactly what I was looking for but when I run it, it seems that it sees my image based pdfs as just text files and says there are thousands of words/characters in them. I have a feeling that I am missing something.....I see various forum postings on the web regarding itextsharp and searching words in pdfs (no idea if this is it or not)?
Hoping someone can point me in the right direction (a specific example of this on the web somewhere) would be very much appreciated.

Gully

Comment: A PDF file is not a plain-text file. That code you found will never be able to to what it claims on pdf's..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. 
Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. BTW, a `.pdf` is a **binary file**;  and `Measure-Object` calculates the numeric properties of objects, and the characters, words, and lines *in string objects*, such as **files of text**. Hence, described approach _must_ fail.

Comment: OK - thanks for the information. Back to the drawing board (finding a solution) - sounds like Powershell is not it.

Comment: How do you determine if something is 'image based' or not.  Like, is a graphic novel?  Is it art?  If it's pictures of animals with text, is that image based?  To begin to suceed here, you need to define what is in scope.

Comment: They seemed to be called "Image-only" or scanned pdfs. These would be any pdf where text cannot be found. https://pdf.abbyy.com/learning-center/pdf-types/

Comment: So are you just looking for any/all pdfs? `Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -Filter "*.pdf" -Recurse"`.

Comment: Yes - within a number of directories/folders. Over the years, end users have sent thousands of pdfs to be posted on our website - many of them being just scanned versions (they could not locate the original digital copy so they just used a scanner and created a pdf from the paper copy). Trying to find an easy way to identify them without having to open each one of them up and checking.

Comment: If you're talking about image-based documents (scanned, most likely?) then you may want to take a look at pdfOCR, an add-on for iText 7: https://itextpdf.com/en/products/itext-7/pdf-ocr-text-recognition (the iTextSharp you mentioned is actually iText 5 .NET).

Comment: Okay now I ready your question a bit better. Are you looking for a way to distinguish between a text-based PDF and an image-based PDF? Or are you asking a different question?

Comment: Hi Amedee - yes, that is correct.

Comment: You may be able to do this with the free commandline tool `pdftotext.exe`, which is part of [Xpdf command line tools](http://www.xpdfreader.com/download.html). Then use as `$content = 'Path\To\pdftotext.exe' -q 'Path\To\ThePDF.pdf' '-'; if  ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($content) { <# No text, this could be image only #> }`